# iOS App Intents UI Extension calling configureView multiple times and displaying my view multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, intents-extension

I am using the IntentsExtension and IntentsUIExtension for a messaging app to allow a user to send messages using Siri.

It all works and the message is sent once, however when the extension UI is displayed, the view I define in configureView is displayed 3 times.

This is the default code intent handler.  Either using this default code or my custom code the result is the same.  UI extension IntentViewController configureView method called 3 times:

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension, INSendMessageIntentHandling, INSearchForMessagesIntentHandling, INSetMessageAttributeIntentHandling {
    
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        // This is the default implementation.  If you want different objects to handle different intents,
        // you can override this and return the handler you want for that particular intent.
        
        return self
    }
    
    // MARK: - INSendMessageIntentHandling
    
    // Implement resolution methods to provide additional information about your intent (optional).
    func resolveRecipients(for intent: INSendMessageIntent, with completion: @escaping ([INSendMessageRecipientResolutionResult]) -> Void) {
        if let recipients = intent.recipients {
            
            // If no recipients were provided we'll need to prompt for a value.
            if recipients.count == 0 {
                completion([INSendMessageRecipientResolutionResult.needsValue()])
                return
            }
            
            var resolutionResults = [INSendMessageRecipientResolutionResult]()
            for recipient in recipients {
                let matchingContacts = [recipient] // Implement your contact matching logic here to create an array of matching contacts
                switch matchingContacts.count {
                case 2  ... Int.max:
                    // We need Siri's help to ask user to pick one from the matches.
                    resolutionResults += [INSendMessageRecipientResolutionResult.disambiguation(with: matchingContacts)]
                    
                case 1:
                    // We have exactly one matching contact
                    resolutionResults += [INSendMessageRecipientResolutionResult.success(with: recipient)]
                    
                case 0:
                    // We have no contacts matching the description provided
                    resolutionResults += [INSendMessageRecipientResolutionResult.unsupported()]
                    
                default:
                    break
                    
                }
            }
            completion(resolutionResults)
        } else {
            completion([INSendMessageRecipientResolutionResult.needsValue()])
        }
    }
    
    func resolveContent(for intent: INSendMessageIntent, with completion: @escaping (INStringResolutionResult) -> Void) {
        if let text = intent.content, !text.isEmpty {
            completion(INStringResolutionResult.success(with: text))
        } else {
            completion(INStringResolutionResult.needsValue())
        }
    }
    
    // Once resolution is completed, perform validation on the intent and provide confirmation (optional).
    
    func confirm(intent: INSendMessageIntent, completion: @escaping (INSendMessageIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        // Verify user is authenticated and your app is ready to send a message.
        
        let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: NSStringFromClass(INSendMessageIntent.self))
        let response = INSendMessageIntentResponse(code: .ready, userActivity: userActivity)
        completion(response)
    }
    
    // Handle the completed intent (required).
    
    func handle(intent: INSendMessageIntent, completion: @escaping (INSendMessageIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        // Implement your application logic to send a message here.
        
        let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: NSStringFromClass(INSendMessageIntent.self))
        let response = INSendMessageIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: userActivity)
        completion(response)
    }
    
    // Implement handlers for each intent you wish to handle.  As an example for messages, you may wish to also handle searchForMessages and setMessageAttributes.
    
    // MARK: - INSearchForMessagesIntentHandling
    
    func handle(intent: INSearchForMessagesIntent, completion: @escaping (INSearchForMessagesIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        // Implement your application logic to find a message that matches the information in the intent.
        
        let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: NSStringFromClass(INSearchForMessagesIntent.self))
        let response = INSearchForMessagesIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: userActivity)
        // Initialize with found message's attributes
        response.messages = [INMessage(
            identifier: "identifier",
            content: "I am so excited about SiriKit!",
            dateSent: Date(),
            sender: INPerson(personHandle: INPersonHandle(value: "sarah@example.com", type: .emailAddress), nameComponents: nil, displayName: "Sarah", image: nil,  contactIdentifier: nil, customIdentifier: nil),
            recipients: [INPerson(personHandle: INPersonHandle(value: "+1-415-555-5555", type: .phoneNumber), nameComponents: nil, displayName: "John", image: nil,  contactIdentifier: nil, customIdentifier: nil)]
            )]
        completion(response)
    }
    
    // MARK: - INSetMessageAttributeIntentHandling
    
    func handle(intent: INSetMessageAttributeIntent, completion: @escaping (INSetMessageAttributeIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        // Implement your application logic to set the message attribute here.
        
        let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: NSStringFromClass(INSetMessageAttributeIntent.self))
        let response = INSetMessageAttributeIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: userActivity)
        completion(response)
    }
}
```

and the UI code:

```
class IntentViewController: UIViewController, INUIHostedViewControlling {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
        
    // MARK: - INUIHostedViewControlling
    
    // Prepare your view controller for the interaction to handle.
    func configureView(for parameters: Set<INParameter>, of interaction: INInteraction, interactiveBehavior: INUIInteractiveBehavior, context: INUIHostedViewContext, completion: @escaping (Bool, Set<INParameter>, CGSize) -> Void) {
        // Do configuration here, including preparing views and calculating a desired size for presentation.
        completion(true, parameters, self.desiredSize)
    }
    
    var desiredSize: CGSize {
        return self.extensionContext!.hostedViewMaximumAllowedSize
    }
    
}
```

Putting a breakpoint on the completion handler in configureView I can see it is called 3 times.  In my app this causes the custom view to appear 3 times one after another stacked vertically.

Comment: Where is `IntentViewController` being initialised? Add relevant functions/code for that as well

Comment: I believe the initialization occurs when the completion in the intent handler above is called.  This is all the code above.  This is used to send a message using Siri.  The view controller is in the IntentsUIExtension

Comment: Okay, but where is `configureView` being called then?

Comment: configureView is not called by me.  not sure if it's a delegate but that is all handled by the extension.

Comment: I am experiencing this as well, any solution found?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the reason the delegate function

```
func configureView(for parameters: Set<INParameter>, of interaction: INInteraction, interactiveBehavior: INUIInteractiveBehavior, context: INUIHostedViewContext, completion: @escaping (Bool, Set<INParameter>, CGSize) -> Void)
```

was being called multiple times. It is because the method is called for each parameter in the `for parameters: Set<INParameter>` argument.

I solved my issue by combining the contents of the message into the `content` field of the INMessage initializer

```
response.sentMessages = [
      INMessage(
         identifier: "SentMessage"
         , content: recipientName + "," + message // combined here
         , dateSent: nil
         , sender: nil
         , recipients: nil)
]
```

Then in the `configureView()` I have the following:

```
if let response = interaction.intentResponse as? INSendMessageIntentResponse
     , parameters.count > 0
{
     if response.code == .success
     {
          if parameters.contains(INParameter(for: INSendMessageIntent.self, keyPath: "content"))
           , let content = response.sentMessages?.first?.content?.split(separator: ",")
           , let recipientName = content.first
           , let msgText = content.last
          {
               // configure view with params
          }
          completion(true, parameters, CGSize(width: desiredSize.width, height: messageView.frame.height))

          return
    }
}
```